Why does neural network input shape not match image shape?
I have developed a neural network using TensorFlow, and am trying to use it to predict new images. I have loaded a JPEG image as a test example and reformatted it using OpenCV:
formatted_image = cv.resize(image, dsize = (128,128))

Using image.shape returns (128, 128, 3) which is my target.
However, putting this image through model.predict() gives me the following error:
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 128, 128, 3), found shape=(32, 128, 3)

I'm not sure where this value is coming from; I've tried a couple of ways of converting it to a tensor, such as tf_formatted_image = tf.convert_to_tensor(formatted_image, dtype=tf.int8), but this has been unsuccessful.

Not sure where 32 is coming from either, try predicting on np.expand_dims(formatted_image, 0)

Maybe preprocessing the image before passing it to the model.predit() would help.
Try using this code-
tf_formatted_image = tf.convert_to_tensor(formatted_image, dtype=tf.float32)   # converting to TensorFlow tensor
tf_formatted_image = tf.expand_dims(tf_formatted_image, axis=0)
tf_formatted_image = tf_formatted_image / 255.0   #normalizing
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('path_to_model')   #loading the model
predictions = model.predict(tf_formatted_image)


The network seems to accept this input, but unfortunately the output is gibberish. I'm expecting an array of 1s and 0s (integer) but I'm getting a range of floats, including negatives (even if I format the image to int8). But this could be an unrelated issue - I'll keep trying to debug it. In the meantime, thanks for your help!
